# Sonicwall TZ205 route traffic from vpn connection to wan interface on vpn failure

Tags: vpn, sonicwall

We have a Sonicwall TZ205 that has a vpn connection to a Private Verizon network over a hard line internet connection.

If the VPN tunnel fails we want the LAN traffic rerouted to another WAN interface which is directly connected to the Private Verizon network with a cellular modem.

We want this route to active if the VPN tunnel fails and then route the traffic back to the VPN once it is active.

I have looked at a few online answers and have succeeded in rerouting in case of a VPN failure but the traffic will not route back to the VPN once it is active again.

Has anyone experienced this?

The Sonicwall is using SonicOS Enhanced 5.8.1.13-1o.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You had to use tunnel-based VPN and set the appropriate route inside Network->Routing table. For more information, consults the Administration Manual.